# User registration on sub site

Tags: multisite, user-registration

I have configured multi-site wordpress. I have some sub-sites as like **site1.mydomain.com** and **site2.mydomain.com**. Now i just want to enable the user registration on my sub-sites.

When a user clicks on register link in any sub-site (site1.mydomain.com or site2.mydomain.com) **it takes them to the main site**(mydomain.com) and register them as an administrater of another site. so he will be having another site as (site2.mydomain.com).

But i want is that, if the user clicks the register link on the sub-site (ex:site1.mydomain.com) they **should be register only on that sub-site itself and become the member only for that site with some roles**.

I am very new to wordpress. I dont even know the coding standard of the wordpress. But i hope i can manage these things. Now i am just roaming around with the plugins.

Please some one help me for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you've described is default behavior for WordPress where when a user registers on a subsite, they're really registering with the root site.

Check out this plugin, which looks to help with new user sign ups and adding them to the right subsite.

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wpmu-default-user-role/

If that plugin isn't what you're looking for then perhaps this one is.

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/multisite-user-registration-manager/

A couple options for you to check out.

A word of advice, **be sure to back everything up (including your database!)** in case something goes wrong, you have a way to go back to a working site.

Comment: Thank you pat. The **multi-site user registration manager plugin was helped me**. I am checking over the coding to customize to make the **user get register directly without requesting**. Do you have any idea on this? Anyway thanks for your help pat.

Answer (score 1):

There is a new plugin that covers this functionality..
https://wordpress.org/plugins/network-subsite-user-registration/

its based on the guidance from https://halfelf.org/2012/multisite-registration/ and extends this to create a simple plugin solution allowing the networkwide activation to be seemless to the user registration on the subsite.